# To add line counter in Buffer reader Java

Tags: java, bufferedreader

> I am given a task where I should use a buffered reader to read a file,
>   plus count the number of lines in my file. 
>   After doing so I should Split and Parse it. Can someone help?

```
package javaapplication12;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;



public class JavaApplication12 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String count= "F:\\Gephi\\number.txt";

                BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;

        try {


            fr = new FileReader(count);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);


            String sCurrentLine;

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }


                    }    

                catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
```

Somewhere around here, I guess there should be a code reading number of line in a file
                        finally {

```
            try {

                if (br != null)
                    br.close();

                if (fr != null)
                    fr.close();

            } 

                        catch (IOException ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();

            }


                        if (count != null);
```

Here should be the splitting part

```
                        String[] temp = count.split("/t");
```

After splitting there should a for loop and using an array, it should be parsed

```
}




    }

}
```

Comment: Well, there's LineNumberReader already in the JDK: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html

Comment: You need to word your question better. Its really difficult to understand what exactly you are trying to do. Please be more specific. Also, please try to add comments to your code example here as you would in your actial code, using // notation. That way, lines of code that are supposed to go together are visible as such. Also, Im not sure about what exactly "count" is supposed to be. It looks like its the file path but at the end it looks like its the content. But at the same time from your question it sounds like there should be a linecount.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lines` method in `BufferedReader` to get a `Stream` of lines, split each line, and collect it to a `List`

```
List<String[]> lines;
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path"))) {
    lines = reader.lines()
        .map(line -> line.split("\t"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to read your code. Please format it the next time.

I have created a file called "random_file.txt". Its contents are the following:

> This is line 1 ...
>
> And this is line number 2
>
> This is another line ...
>
> And one more
>
> And another one

Now we can do all the things you need with the file. We can count the lines, print each one of them or parse them. Since you don't exactly specified what you want to parse, I wrote an example method, that just counts a specific word in the file. Parsing should be done by using RegularExpressions (regex). Here is a good link for that:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileParser
{
    private String filepath;

    public FileParser(String inputFilePath)
    {
        this.filepath = inputFilePath;
    }

    /**
     * Counts the number of lines.
     * 
     * @return Number of lines.
     * 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException If the file doesn't exist.
     * @throws IOException When an IO error occures.
     */
    public int countLines() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        File file = new File(filepath);

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        int counter = 0;
        while (br.readLine() != null)
        {
            counter++;
        }

        return counter;
    }

    /**
     * Splits the lines of the file and returns a list.
     * Each element of the list represents one line.
     * Note that the line seperator is excluded.
     * 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException If the file doesn't exist.
     * @throws IOException When an IO error occures.
     */
    public List<String> splitLines1() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        File file = new File(filepath);

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String line;
        ArrayList<String> outputList = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            outputList.add(line);
        }

        if (br != null) br.close();
        return outputList;
    }

    /**
     * Splits the lines of the file and returns a String.
     * Same as before, but now we have the line seperators included.
     * 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException If the file doesn't exist.
     * @throws IOException When an IO error occures.
     */
    public String splitLines2() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        File file = new File(filepath);

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String line;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // we append every line to the builder
            // note that we get one line seperator more than
            // necessary (the one in the end)
            builder.append(line + System.lineSeparator());
        }

        if (br != null) br.close();
        return builder.toString();
    }

    /**
     * An example method for parsing. In this method we count the
     * number of times a word occures in given file.
     * 
     * @param word The word we are looking for.
     * 
     * @return Count the word occurencies.
     * 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException If the file doesn't exist.
     * @throws IOException When an IO error occures.
     */
    public int countOccurencies(String word)
            throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        List<String> fileLines = splitLines1(); // get the list, where each element represents one line
        int counter = 0;
        for (String line : fileLines)
        {
            // we split each line into words by splitting
            // at the spaces
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
            {
                if (words[i].equals(word)) counter++;
            }
        }

        return counter;
    }

    /**
     * Testing the methods.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // Location of my file is in the project folder
        String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator
                + "random_file.txt";
        FileParser fp = new FileParser(filePath);

        System.out.println("The file has " + fp.countLines() + " lines."
                + System.lineSeparator());

        System.out.println("We print a list holding each line as an element:");
        System.out.println(fp.splitLines1()
            .toString() + System.lineSeparator());

        System.out
            .println("Now we print the file contents as a single string:");
        System.out.println(fp.splitLines2());

        System.out
            .println("Now we count the occurencies of the word \"line\":");
        System.out.println(fp.countOccurencies("line"));
    }
}
```

Here is the console output:

```
The file has 5 lines.

We print a list holding each line as an element:
[This is line 1 ..., And this is line number 2, This is another line ..., And one more, And another one]

Now we print the file contents as a single string:
This is line 1 ...
And this is line number 2
This is another line ...
And one more
And another one

Now we count the occurencies of the word "line":
3
```

Comment: I' m grateful to you for ur help, actually, I'm new to stack overflow, pls forgive me for any of my mistakes, I'll keep in mind and try to post properly next time.! TQ

Comment: No problem, hope it helped.